# Listen to Ref<string> change in Vue even if value is changed to 0 then the old one

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got into a problem with Vue3's `watch` or `onUpdated`:

I can trigger the callback normally with both, but let's I got a senario below:

1. A user click Delete button, and set the `targetId` to `someId`
2. `<Modal/>`'s `watch` was triggered because `props.id` was changed, so a bootstrap Modal show up
3. User misclicked on outside the modal and cause the modal to hide.
4. User click Delete button again, but this time, `targetId` was already `someId`, so `<Modal/>`'s `watch` will not be triggered. And no modal will shown up

You can see in my code I tried to set `targetId` to 0 everytime `showModal` was called, but no help. In my opinion, `targetId` did change, twice, but don't know why it's not "watched" by `<Modal/>`

**Basically I want to trigger `watch` or `onUpdated` even if old value is equel to the new value(I know this is not possiable in a direct way, so I tried to set it to a default value, then change it back, hoping to trigger "oldVal -> 0" and "0 -> oldVal" two changes, but no help.)**

```html
<!-- Parent -->
<template>
  <button @onclick="showDeleteModal(someId)">Delete</buton>
  <Modal :id="targetId"/>
</template>

<script setup>
   const targetId = ref(0)
   const showDeleteModal = (id)=>{
      <!-- change to 0 then change back to id does not work -->
      targetId.value = 0
      targetId.value = id
   }
</script>



<!-- Child(Modal) -->
<template>
   some template
</template>

<script setup>
   const props = defineProps({id: Number})
   watch(()=>props.id, ()=>{
      <!-- Show the Modal -->
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value back and forth in the same function doesn't work, because change detection will only trigger after the function has concluded. You could use [`nextTick()`](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick):

```
import { nextTick } from 'vue'
const showDeleteModal = (id)=>{
  targetId.value = 0
  nextTick(() => targetId.value = id)
}
```

However, this will trigger the modal twice, and it is an awkward solution.

From your description, it sounds like it might be possible to remove the id when the modal closes. If that is an option, I would go with that.

Comment: Thanks for answering! `nextTick()` is a new trick for me, and after I read the doc, I solved the problem. 

And more, I think about the question, and simpilified it as: "Show the modal when ever the button is clicked", so no need to listen to change because the modal will show no matter what `targetId` is set to.